# How to point stylesheet CDN to internal source in .ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cdn

I get Mixed Content error in the browser when running application in production.
The reason is that my Ajax ScriptManager wants to load the css files with content delivery network.
i have found a way to stop scripts from loading through CDN by specifying the path and point to a internal source.

```
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(
         "MicrosoftAjax.js",
         ext,
         new ScriptResourceDefinition
         {
             ResourceName = "MicrosoftAjax.js",
             ResourceAssembly = ext,
             CdnPath = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
             CdnDebugPath = "~/Scripts/WebForms/MsAjax/MicrosoftAjax.js",
             CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true
         }
     );
```

My question is how can i do this for the style sheets so they load from internal ?

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/act/17_1_1/Content/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Calendar.css

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/act/17_1_1/Content/AjaxControlToolkit/Styles/Backgrounds.css

and other css i need to load

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Originaly it was pure webforms last year it was moved into mvc, but the specific view i have the problem is still .aspx

Comment: You can do MVC with aspx. Razor and .cshtml wasn't introduced until MVC3, and the WebFormsViewEngine is still supported. Even if you do MVC with .aspx, you shouldn't use that API.

Comment: You might be able to control with Bundle.config. (?)

Comment: No i need to set the CDN-path, i can not use bundle. AjaxToolbox is rendering the scripts it needs when the view is generated, and it renders the script through CDN(content delivery network), and i need to be able to specify that path